# C# Display ComboBox's based on Int number

Tags: c#, dynamic, combobox

First a bit of background information. I am playing an online campaign of D&D and am playing a druid. I already build an animal-tracker, for all my summoned animals, but now I want to speed things up a bit more by building a character tracker, for my own character, Duncan, as well as for my Mighty Eddy (dire-wolf animal companion).

The thing I am now working on, is keeping track of my spells. In D&D spells and spell levels are based on the level of the character and bonus stats.

For Druid: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Druid
For Bonusses: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Ability_Scores

Scroll down for Ability modifiers, so the more wisdom, the more spells.

Now, I am thinking of making tab-controlled pages, for spells ranging from level0 to level9 and then displaying ComboBoxes to select the spell(s) you want to prepare.

Innitially, I was planning on hiding the vast majority of comboboxes and only unhiding them with simple If statement, so if wisdom is high enough, unhide x amount of combo boxes....but that will mean creating loads of IF statements.

Is there a way to say, IF Wisdom is high enough for 10 spells, display 10 combo boxes, if wisdom is high enough for only 5, display only 5?

Or does anyone else have a good alternative idea on how to do this? I am open for suggestions.

Comment: just post your code and problem in it, you have stated Domain and problem

Comment: Simple answer is yes, correct answer depends on what you are using, what controls you have on your form... what platform... the list is endless almost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** since you didn't specify a language **or** a platform I'm going to use C# and Windows Forms.

Sure, I'm not sure how you determine the wisdom level, but let's say it's stored in a variable named `_wisdomLevel`:

```
private int _wisdomLevel;
```

now you just need a `Dictionary` to handle that:

```
private Dictionary<int, int> _wisdomLevelSpells = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        { 1, 5 },
        { 2, 5 },
        { 3, 10 },
    }
```

Now, the values I put in there are random, they are so you can get the idea. Now to display those combo boxes I might do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _wisdomLevelSpells[_wisdomLevel]; i++)
{
    this.Controls.Add(new ComboBox()
        {
            DataSource = ...,
            ValueMember = ...,
            DisplayMember = ...,
        }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I will give this a shot, looks like what I am looking for. And indeed, C# with Windows Forms.